# Unable to find jar for weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException

Tags: weblogic, classpath

I'm unable to find jar for 
weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException.

I am running an application on WebLogic 12c which throws the below error and i'm thinking if I keep the jar in the classpath , it would work but have not been able to find the correct jar.

The error I get is below

```
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:1026)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:987)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.doFindClass(GenericClassLoader.java:608)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:540)
        at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:493)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Comment: The jar is located under MW_HOME/wlserver/modules/com.oracle.weblogic.jms.jar

Comment: I checked the jar "com.oracle.weblogic.jms.jar" , it doesn't have this class "ResourceAllocationException"

However, I did find this class in another jar javax.javaee-api.jar and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found the class "ResourceAllocationException"  in another jar javax.javaee-api.jar and that did the trick for me.

Comment: javax.javaee-api.jar does not contain weblogic classes so you wont find weblogic.jms.common.ResourceAllocationException in it, or you are looking for another class...

Comment: @EmmanuelCollin javax.javaee-api.jar contains the ResourceAllocationException jar in the javax.jms package.  I was not able to find the ResourceAllocationException class in any of the weblogic jars.